# Open modal component when submit axios post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, modal-dialog, axios

I have an `onSubmit` function with an `axios` post that allows to register a user.

I would like to know if it is possible if when the user create his account, at the time of the submission a open modal with a **timeout** ?

I already have the component of the modal created with redux but I do not know how to integrate it in this `Axios`

**Axios Post**

```
const onSubmit = async function onSubmit(values) {
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:4242/registerUser',
        data: values,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
        .then((res) => {
            localStorage.setItem("token", res.headers["x-access-token"])

        })
        .catch(function (erreur) {
            console.log(erreur);
        })
}
```

**Modal Reducer**

```
export const registerModal = id => ({
  type: "REGISTER_MODAL",
  id
});

export const showModal = id => ({
  type: "SHOW_MODAL",
  id
});

export const hideModal = id => ({
  type: "HIDE_MODAL",
  id
});

const initialState = {
  // modals: []
  modals: {}
};

const modals = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "REGISTER_MODAL":
      const newModal = {
        id: action.id,
        visible: false
      };
      return {
        ...state,
        modals: { ...state.modals, [action.id]: newModal }
      };
    case "SHOW_MODAL":
      return {
        ...state,
        modals: {
          ...state.modals,
          [action.id]: { ...state.modals[action.id], visible: true }
        }
      };
    case "HIDE_MODAL":
      return {
        ...state,
        modals: {
          ...state.modals,
          [action.id]: { ...state.modals[action.id], visible: false }
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default combineReducers({
  modals
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm missing something, but it looks like you need the `dispatch` function in your actions

Answer (score 0):

Ok if i get it right you want to open the modal after the post was received.. 
So I would try to put the action of the open modal inside the then method o request promise:

```
const onSubmit = async function onSubmit(values) {
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:4242/registerUser',
        data: values,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
        .then((res) => {
            localStorage.setItem("token", res.headers["x-access-token"])
            // Here you are sure that your post was successfull I think...
            // The issue here will be to get the res and the dispatcher function, this will vary for the pattern that you are following 
           modalReducer.showModal( res.id );
        })
        .catch(function (erreur) {
            console.log(erreur);
        })
}
```

A thing that i cant solve is how are you using your reducer inside the Component that is handling your post.You are passing the id? or the id already exist in the component?.